# Why sometimes URLs are reached without the "www"'s in the url?

Tags: url, no-www

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does WWW do?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14457/what-does-www-do)

The usual form of an internet adress is for example `http://www.example.com`. Sometimes I encounter pages, that have the `www` missing, like in this real world example:

```
https://service.discoplus.de/
```

Why is that so?

If I type in `https://wwwservice.discoplus.de/` (with www) it asks me a security question and then rerouts me to `http://www.discoplus.de/`. So obviously internet adresses with and without `www` are not equivalent.

Thanks for any enlightening!

Comment: you might want to see this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14457/what-does-www-do

Comment: You may also want to read this: "Why does my site only work with a www in the URL?": http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25071/why-does-my-site-only-work-with-a-www-in-the-url

Answer (score 0):

A URL is composed of [Protocol][Domain][Folder and File Structure]

The part you're asking about is the domain part, ans domains have a few rules. But trying to keep it simple, the normal www in websites represents a particular machine (the web server) and is not mandatory, but its only supported if explicit in the DNS structure od the domain.

More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web#WWW_prefix)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this:

The domain is `discoplus.de`
Anything before that:

```
service.discoplus.de, 
mail.discoplus.de,
www.discoplus.de
```

are subdomains. This allows multiple resources under the same domain. A subdomain may even be close to public. Like on a intranet.

For practical reasons nowadays most web servers are configured to redirect `www.domain.com` and domain.com to same place. So it may look like they are the same but in fact they are just separate addresses both pointing to a single address.

When you type `https://wwwservice.discoplus.de/` you are being redirected probably becuase that URL doesnt exist you are redirected to a starting page.

The orther thing is the protocol.

when its `http://` it refers to HyperText Transfer Protocol which is a standart protocol for web pages. if it has an "s" like `https://` this means its secure* and the data being transferred is encrypted.